# Issues using PL/SQL function body to generate a sql script

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am currently trying to create a list view that pulls the records from a different table depending on different information.  I figured the best way to do this would be to use a PL/SQL function body that returned a SQL script as the source of the list view region.

Here is the code I started with:

```
DECLARE
    list_query varchar2(4000);
    table_name varchar2(4000);
    table_prefix varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    select TABLE_NAME into table_prefix 
    from ASSEMBLIES_TABLE
    where ASSEMBLY_ID = :P21_PASSED_ASSEMBLY; 
    
    table_name := table_prefix || :P21_PASSED_TABLE;
    list_query := 'select
                      CRITERIA_ID,
                      CRITERIA_NAME,
                      PART_ID,
                      PART_NAME
                   from
                      ' || table_name || '
                   where 
                      PART_ID = ' || :P21_PASSED_PART || '';
    return(list_query);
END;
```

This script resulted in an error titled ORA-01403: no data found.  I ended up wrapping a BEGIN EXCEPTION END block around my select into statement and now the code looks like this.

```
DECLARE
    list_query varchar2(4000);
    table_name varchar2(4000);
    table_prefix varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        select TABLE_NAME into table_prefix 
        from ASSEMBLIES_TABLE where ASSEMBLY_ID = :P21_PASSED_ASSEMBLY; 
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN table_prefix := 'CABLES';
    END;
    table_name := table_prefix || :P21_PASSED_TABLE;
    
    list_query := 'select
                      CRITERIA_ID,
                      CRITERIA_NAME,
                      PART_ID,
                      PART_NAME
                   from
                      ' || table_name || '
                   where 
                      PART_ID = ' || :P21_PASSED_PART || '';
    return(list_query);
END;
```

With this code the no data found error has gone away but a new error popped up:

ORA-20999: Parsing returned query results in "ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query!

ORA-06550: line 12, column 6: ORA-00936: missing expression
While wrapping the select into statement in the EXCEPTION block got rid of the no data found error it makes me nervous that even if I do get this code to compile/validate that the exception will always trigger. If anyone could help with either of these two errors I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly are you assigning to :P21_PASSED_TABLE and :P21_PASSED_PART?

Comment: :P21_PASSED_TABLE is a varchar2(400) pulled directly from a table and :P21_PASSED_PART is the read value from a select list and is a variable type number(6,1).

Comment: Taking another look, I suspect something you are assigning to :P21_PASSED_ASSEMBLY is causing the parsing error. It's going to be hard to isolate the offending value without some trial and error. I would start by plugging in some simple test values to make sure it works as expected, then test further with values from your table.

Comment: I can't even get this code to work at run time as it won't compile or validate if this is the case doesn't that mean that what is specifically getting passed couldn't be problematic?

Comment: Try hard coding values for  :P21_PASSED_ASSEMBLY and :P21_PASSED_TABLE and :P21_PASSED_PART and run it as anon block. Does it still error?

Comment: To my surprise, the error goes away and everything looks correct at runtime.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: You bet, good luck!